# Egyptian Fraction when numerator is greater than denominator

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, egyptian-fractions

I am doing an assignment about Egyptian fractions and I am a bit confused about what to do when the given fraction's numerator is greater than denominator. My initial idea was to subtract the fraction by 1, 1/2, 1/3 etc and when the numerator becomes less than denominator I would apply the proper algorithm. And I saw that this way does not work out. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

EDIT: I cannot subtract by 1 because it will not be an Egyptian fraction.

Comment: Convert to a mixed number first, I think.

Comment: To be honest I don't want my number to have the form 1 + 1+1+ 1/n1. In the final representation each 1/n for n belongs to natural numbers, should be appeared one time.

Comment: Right, it'd be, for instance, 17/5 = 3 + 1/3 + 1/15

Comment: I don't want that too

Comment: Norm is to let the integer part be a single term, with denominator $1$ as it were.  Thus if you ask [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=egyptian+fraction+7%2F2) for the egyptian fraction representation of $\frac 72$ it will return $3+\frac 12$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your trick is pretty close to getting what you want, but you stop too early. As you probably know, the series
$$
1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \cdots
$$
diverges, which means that for any initial value $\frac pq$ you started with, there is an $n$ such that
$$
H_n = 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1n \leq \frac pq < 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1{n+1} = H_{n+1}.
$$
Now, you can look at the rational $\frac pq - H_n$, which must be less than $\frac1{n+1}$. Thus, if we apply any ordinary Egyptian fraction algorithm that works for fractions less than 1, you get a representation of $\frac pq - H_n$, and any term in this Egyptian fraction decomposition will have denominator greater than $n + 1$. Now just add $H_n$ back to this representation, and you have a decomposition of $\frac pq$ of the form that you are looking for.

Comment: As $H_n \approx \ln n+0.577$ if the integer part of the number to be expressed is at all large it will take a *lot* of terms.  If we want $H_n \gt 10$ we need $n$ about $12370$

Comment: True, but also note that this is basically optimal; within the constraints given by OP, $H_n$ is the "fastest" way to get the value down to below 1.

Comment: I agree.  I just thought it good to show how slow it is.

Comment: In the particular case of $\frac{17}{15}$ I used above, this gives $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{13\ 889}{720\ 720}$, which expands finally to $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{52} + \frac{1}{24\ 853} + \frac{1}{1\ 053\ 650\ 245} + \frac{1}{3\ 774\ 608\ 050\ 827\ 453\ 840}$

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much this looks good.